# When i click on a menu item via onClickListener, it says the class is absent although it is present. How do i fix it?

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is my menu class

```
package devgan.jatin.com.myapplication;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Menu extends ListActivity {
private final String[] classes={"StartingPoint","GFX"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese=classes[position];


    try {
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.jatin.devgan."+cheese);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

This is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".StartingPoint">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.jatin.devgan.STARTINGPOINT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.jatin.devgan.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here's what I did. Created a splash screen which goes to the menu. 
You can see the menu class up. When i intend to start an activity of StartingPoint through the menu, its gives me ClassNotFoundException-

but the thing is when i tweaked my code to go straight from splash screen to StartingPoint, it works fine! I'm baffled.
All software is up to date.

Comment: I think the problem is, that your class name is wrong. In your Manifest, the `class` is defined like `".StartingPoint"` and your Class name in your Intent is `"com.jatin.devgan."+cheese` which results in `com.jatin.devgan.StartingPoint"`. I think you have to set `com.jatin.devgan.StartingPoint` in your mainfest also...but that´s just an assumption.

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error. thanks anyway

Comment: ok, so please post the logcat stacktrace...

Comment: For context I followed the same procedure i saw in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYyAJQ7Vw&index=21&list=PLEFA63803DBD4C83A

Comment: also what is logcat stack trace?

Comment: this is the output with errors in your logcat window......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just implement a switch method, to start the activity based on the switch ?

```
    ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.LV);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,int position, long l) {
            switch (position)
            {
                case 1 : 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OtherClass.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }break;
                case 2: 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OtherClass.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    });
```